# Apache Kafka patch release upgrade process

Tags: apache-kafka, upgrade

I'm new to Apache Kafka cluster upgrade, and I'm wondering if there's a procedure in order to upgrade Apache Kafka 2.6.1 to 2.6.2 (in a rolling way). Apache documentation in not clear about steps to made in order to apply this upgrade/patch.

Answer (score 0):

For patch releases with unchanging interbroker & log versions, you only need to follow step 2 - graceful stop, upgrade, then restart

http://kafka.apache.org/26/documentation.html#upgrade